# Nivo lib display a single point on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-visualization, nivo-react

I am discovering the Nivo lib for data visualization and I am blocking on a feature that I would like to achieve.

Here is an example of what I would like to do : https://nivo.rocks/line/

I would like to make a component with an almost similar rendering except that: the curves should appear without the points.
Then, hover the mouse over the curve only the point that you hover should appear
and when we move the mouse elsewhere the previous point disappears to make room for the next one

Apparently the lib does not manage natively, we can make the points disappear / appear but only all or none and not manage them individually.

If you have any suggestions I'm interested, thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe post the code you already wrote, it might help

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm trying to do the same.